# How to add special attribute to element if has class 'on' or not using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have some dynamical list

And if 'LI' element has class name 'on', 
add attribute `"aria-hidden=false"`.

Also if LI element has not class name 'on',
add attribute `"aria-hidden=true"`.

This is my code

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I want the code in DOM

```
<ul class="list">
  <li aria-hidden=true>1</li>
  <li class="on" aria-hidden=false>1</li>
  <li aria-hidden=true>1</li>
  <li aria-hidden=true>1</li>
</ul>
```

How to make it with this code ? Please help

Comment: aria-hidden="false" is not recommended, please read this https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector with [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to target the desired elements the use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to add the attribure

```
//Target all LI elements
var li = $('ul.list li'); 

//Filter li without on class
li.filter(':not(.on)').attr('aria-hidden', true)

//Filter li with on class
li.filter('.on').attr('aria-hidden', false);
```

```js
//Target all LI elements
var li = $('ul.list li'); 

//Filter li without on class
li.filter(':not(.on)').attr('aria-hidden', true)

//Filter li with on class
li.filter('.on').attr('aria-hidden', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$("ul.list li").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-hidden",!$(this).hasClass("on"));
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("ul.list li").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("aria-hidden",!$(this).hasClass("on"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It work inverse. You should use `!$(this).hasClass("on")`

Comment: @Mohammad True, thanks for noticing it, totally missed that i forgot the `!`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').attr('aria-hidden', true);
$('li.on').attr('aria-hidden', false);

//To check if things really changed. Revove it.
console.log($('ul.list').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code add aria-hidden=false to item that has class 'on'

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('ul.list li.on').attr('aria-hidden', true)

  $('ul.list li').attr('aria-hidden', false);
  
})
```

```css
ul.list li.on {
  background:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list">
  <li >item 1</li>
  <li class="on" >item 2</li>
  <li >item 3</li>
  <li >item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: aria-hidden="false" is not recommended, please read this [aria - states_and_properties](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties)

Try this

```js
$(".list li").not('.on').attr('aria-hidden', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about `aria-hidden=false`?

Comment: `aria-hidden="false"` is not recommended, https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with callback function to do this work. In callback check that element has class `on` or not.

```js
$(".list li").attr("aria-hidden", function(){
  return $(this).is(".on") ? false : true;
});
```

```css
[aria-hidden=true] {opacity: 0.5}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="on">1 (.on)</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```